# Java, problema con switch case

Tags: java

Mi código muestra un error en el switch de acuerdo a las variables pero no logro comprender por qué solo imprime lo de ingresar el nombre.

Este es el problema:
Escribir un programa que en un método llamado "datosTrabajador" solicite el nombre de un empleado y su turno asignado y lo devuelva a otro método llamado "calculaHoras" que reciba dichos valores y devuelva el número de horas de labor semanales para imprimirlas en el método main según lo siguiente:

```
DIURNO         8 HORAS DIARIAS

NOCTURNO       7 HORAS DIARIAS

MIXTO          7 1/2 HORAS DIARIAS
```

NOTA: Tomar en cuenta que por cada 6 días de trabajo le corresponde uno de descanso.

Mi código:

```
           import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Trabajador {
        int a,b;
      String  Nocturno="",Diurno="",Mixto="";
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
public int datosTrabajador(){
        
            System.out.print("Ingrese su nombre: ");
            a=leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Turno al que fue asignado: ");
            b=leer.nextInt();

       
            return b;
 }
     public void  calculaHoras(int b){
  
    switch (Nocturno,Mixto,Diurno)
    {
        case "Nocturno":
            System.out.print("Tus horas trabajadas son: "+7*6);
            break;
        case "Diurno":
            System.out.print("Tus horas trabajadas son: "+8*6);
            break;
        case "Mixto":
            System.out.print("Tus horas trabajadas son: "+7.5*6);
            break;
        default:
                System.out.print("Error. Vuelve a ingresar tus datos");
            break;
    }
}

        public static void main(String args[]) {
        Trabajador obj=new Trabajador();
        int b=obj.datosTrabajador();
        obj.calculaHoras(b);
       
 }
 }
```

Comment: Después de la edición tiene más sentido tu pregunta, pero de cualquier manera, la mayoría de los errores son de sintaxis. A un `switch` no le puedes pasar varios argumentos, no puedes guardar `int` en `strings` ni devolver `strings` en lugar de `int`s, las firmas de tus métodos no son correctas. Échale un vistazo a [tu código con arreglitos](https://onlinegdb.com/q5BNXOmWK). ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Esto te será de ayuda: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/index.htm Saludos.

Comment: Sé, por qué es incorrecto y lo que necesitas, pero necesito algo de info: No has especificado qué tiene que ingresar cuando elige el turno: ¿Qué tiene que ingresar cuando el turno es Nocturno, Mixto o Diurno? Observo que recoge un int para saber si es Nocturno, Mixto o Diurno, pero no sé qué valor es cada uno, si me resuleves esta duda te doy la respuesta que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces una switch, has de tener en cuenta que solo puede entrar como parámetro una única variable, los tres datos que introdujiste en la switch debes hacerlo en los cases y en la switch pasar una variable String a la que le darías un valor a través de un scanner.
Seria algo como esto:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String opcion = scan.nextLine();
    switch(opcion) {
    case "Nocturno":
        System.out.println("Asignado al turno Nocturno");
        break;
    case "Mixto":
        System.out.println("Asignado al turno Mixto");
        break;
    case "Diurno":
        System.out.println("Asignado al turno diurno");
        break;
    }
```

Prueba a adaptar esto a tu código y espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo.

Answer (score -4):

Inténtalo así:

```
switch (Nocturno,Mixto,Diurno)
{
    case "Nocturno": 
        // Primero hago el cálculo de las horas y lo guardo en una variable int.
        int horas = 7*6;
        // Luego debo pasar esa variable del tipo int a una String para que 
        //                                  System.out.print() pueda imprimirlo.
        String horasAStr = Integer.toString(horas);
        // Y ahora reemplazo mi código anterior por mi nueva variable
        System.out.print("Tus horas trabajadas son: "+ horasAStr );
        break;
```

Recuerda que los tipos de datos son muy importantes en Java.
Un saludo!

Comment: Un switch NO puede recibir más de una variable... Tampoco necesitas usar `Integer.toString` para concatenar un `int` con una cadena. Por favor, lee cómo responder y visita el centro de ayuda. ¡Bienvenida!